# How to get lenght of dict keys after specific element?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There is a dict

```
example_dict = 

{'spend': '3.91',
 'impressions': '791',
 'clicks': '19',
 'campaign_id': '1111',
 'date_start': '2017-11-01',
 'date_stop': '2019-11-27',
 'age': '18-24',
 'gender': 'male'}
```

I have to check if there are any additional keys after date_stop key and if yes, get the lenght of them and their names.

So far I made a list of keys

```
list_keys = list(example_dict.keys())


list_keys = 
['spend',
 'impressions',
 'clicks',
 'campaign_id',
 'date_start',
 'date_stop',
 'age',
 'gender']
```

And to check that there is 'date_stop' element is simple

```
if 'date_stop' in list_keys:
    # what next
```

But how to proceed am not sure. Appreciate any help.

Comment: in the python dictionary is not sorted by keys, you can't do it.

Comment: ^ But, if you know first 6 keys you can take out the difference between the keys you have and the keys from dictionary

Comment: While dictionary items keep in insertion order on newer Python version, it is not wise to rely on that. If you need order, you are better using a list.

Comment: Why do you need the keys to be in a particular order?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale it could be any number of keys, but date_stop is always among of them

Comment: @Sayse it is Facebook API, the response structure is always like that

Comment: @AnnaDmitrieva - Thats great, but that isn't what i asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be implement in diffrent way, You should be using dict, but if You really want to do this way You could use OrderedDict from collections:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


my_dict = {
    'spend': '3.91',
    'impressions': '791',
    'clicks': '19',
    'campaign_id': '1111',
    'date_start': '2017-11-01',
    'date_stop': '2019-11-27',
    'age': '18-24',
    'gender': 'male'
}


sorted_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

if 'date_stop' in sorted_ordered_dict.keys():
    keys = list(sorted_ordered_dict.keys())
    index = keys.index('date_stop')
    after_list = keys[index:]

    print('len: ', len(after_list))
    print('list: ', after_list)
```

Comment: I can't sort dict unfortunately, the structure should be kept as it is given

Answer (score 1):

use below code:

```
new_dict={}
list_keys = list(example_dict.keys())
k=""
for i in list_keys:
    if 'date_stop' == i:
        k="done"



    if k=="done":
        new_dict[i]=len(i)
```

output:

```
{'date_stop': 9, 'age': 3, 'gender': 6}
```

I hope you understand your question

if you want just name and number of keys use this:

```
new_dict=[]
list_keys = list(example_dict.keys())
k=""
for i in list_keys:
    if 'date_stop' == i:
        k="done"

    if k=="done":
        new_dict.append(i)
```

output:

```
print (new_dict)
print (len(new_dict))

['date_stop', 'age', 'gender']
3
```

Comment: Hello, yeah it is almost perfect, is there any way to filter out date_stop from the result?

Comment: yes, just switch if statement in code :D best regards